# h2o ValueError: No metric tpr

Tags: python, machine-learning, h2o, precision-recall

When trying to acquire the recall score using e.g.

```
rf_model.recall()
```

I get the error:

```
h2o ValueError: No metric tpr
```

I can get other metrics, such as the accuracy, AUC, precision and F1 but no recall...
This is presumably a bug.

If I run:

```
from h2o.model.metrics_base import H2OBinomialModelMetrics as bmm
reporter = bmm(rf_model.metric)
rf_model.metric('recall')
```

I get:

```
Could not find exact threshold 0.0; using closest threshold found 0.0.
```

What is going on?

I am running the h2o version 'h2o-3.15.0.3990'.

I followed the h2o tutorial:

https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-tutorials/blob/master/training/h2o_algos/src/py/decision_tree_ensembles.ipynb

and with using my own dataset, I get the error described above.

Any help?

Also, how does one plot a precision / recall curve using h2o?

Thanks

Comment: Please don't cross-post with the mailing list. (StackOverflow is the better place for this kind of question.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with your 2nd question, Flow has a precision/recall curve (and it is interactive). Flow is always running on port 54321 of each node, i.e. `http://127.0.0.1:54321` if you are running h2o locally.

I imagine that there is something interesting with your data or model, and that when you look at the precision/recall curve it will become clear.

In R if you do `str(m)` (where `m` is your model) you will see all the model data. `m@training_metrics@metrics$thresholds_and_metric_scores$recall` holds the recall numbers for each threshold.

I cannot work out how to look inside the Python object, yet, but your call was correct. On my quick test (the iris dataset with a 2-category enum column added):

```
m.metric("recall")
```

gave:

```
[[0.8160852636726422, 1.0]]
```

And if I want all of the values, it will be something like this:

```
mDL.metric("recall",thresholds=[x/100.0 for x in range(1,100)])
```

giving:

```
Could not find exact threshold 0.01; using closest threshold found 0.010396965719556233.
Could not find exact threshold 0.02; using closest threshold found 0.016617060110009896.
...
Could not find exact threshold 0.92; using closest threshold found 0.9469528904679438.
Could not find exact threshold 0.93; using closest threshold found 0.9469528904679438.
Could not find exact threshold 0.94; using closest threshold found 0.9469528904679438.
Could not find exact threshold 0.95; using closest threshold found 0.9469528904679438.
Could not find exact threshold 0.96; using closest threshold found 0.9469528904679438.
Could not find exact threshold 0.97; using closest threshold found 0.9760293572153097.
Could not find exact threshold 0.98; using closest threshold found 0.9787491606489236.
Could not find exact threshold 0.99; using closest threshold found 0.9909817370067531.

[[0.01, 1.0],
 [0.02, 1.0],
 [0.03, 1.0],
 ...
 [0.87, 1.0],
 [0.88, 1.0],
 [0.89, 0.9850746268656716],
 [0.9, 0.9850746268656716],
 [0.91, 0.9850746268656716],
 [0.92, 0.9850746268656716],
 [0.93, 0.9850746268656716],
 [0.94, 0.9850746268656716],
 [0.95, 0.9850746268656716],
 [0.96, 0.9850746268656716],
 [0.97, 0.9701492537313433],
 [0.98, 0.9552238805970149],
 [0.99, 0.8955223880597015]]
```

(I get such unusual output as it learned my dataset just about perfectly - I suspect that is what has happened with you?) (I foolishly made my binary column a direct function of one of the input columns, with no noise!)